# Run Python Script through Shell Script by Double Click

Tags: python, bash, shell, executable

I have a `runGUI.sh` script and I want to run a Python script through it. The Python Script is a `GUI.py` that I want to make it run as an App, by either double clicking the Shell script or the Python Script itself (ideally I would like to have both ways).

I tried everything that others recommend:

- I changed permissions to both scripts and also made them executable.
- I added the appropriate `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` in the Shell Script and `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the Python Script.
- I tried all combinations in the Shell script for the Python executable command, like `python GUI.py` or `./GUI.py`, and even with the full path of the Python Script.

The result is the same. If I double click the GUI.py or the runGUI.sh, and because they are executable, I get the options:

[Options when double clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6blgb.png)

Regardless of "Run in Terminal" or "Run", nothing happens.

If I run either scripts through terminal, like `./GUI.py` or `runGUI.sh`, the Python file works fine and the GUI is opening in both cases.

Is there a way to open this GUI by double clicking the Shell or Python scripts?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, standard Gnome, have installed Zshell if this helps and I built the Python GUI with the Tkinter module.

Comment: we need to know your OS and desktop environment

Comment: @glennjackman I am using Ubuntu 16.04, I have also installed the Zshell. I have the stock Gnome, if this answers the question of Desktop Environment. I built the Python GUI with the Tkinter module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diego is mostly correct, but they left out one important detail that will cause it to fail. I am assuming you are using a python terminal application. It should look more like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=My GUI
Exec=python3 /path/to/GUI.py
Terminal=true
```

The `Terminal=true` makes it so it actually runs when you click on it. Also, put your python alias (python3,py,python,etc.) before it. Lastly, if you don't want an icon, just omit it rather than putting `Icon=`.

I know this is an old question, but I would have forgotten it too if I ran into this issue any less recently.

Comment: good point about `Terminal` however **GUI** seems to indicate it does not need it and I would leave the `shebang` and execution permission to decide how to run `/path/to/GUI.py` instead of prepending an interpreter

Comment: Good comment, but by the fact OP put `runGui` leads me to think it is a script that initially starts in the terminal, like a kivy application

Answer (score 3):

Create a file name `mygui.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=My GUI
Icon=
Exec=/path/to/GUI.py
```

and then `mygui` will be appearing as an application that you can launch clicking it.

Comment: It works really well as an alternative. Thanks a lot for the help. It's great. I think my issue with the way I was trying to implement it, was something to do with permission to the python side. Thanks a lot.