# Script not executing on click

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, debian

I have a python script on my desktop that I want to execute by clicking on it. I have permissions set and all that, but it won't launch by clicking on it.
I can start it using the terminal and everything works as expected.

Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['python', '/filepath/EDITOR.py'])

subprocess.run(['python', '/filepath/ULTRASOUND_SIMULATOR.py'])
```

I've been able to launch the "ULTRASOUND_SIMULATOR.py" script from the desktop with a click.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env/python` is incorrect. It should be `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

Comment: I have tried that, and "python 3", and still nothing.
I click, it offers 4 options: - execute, execute in terminal, open, cancel. 
Neither executes do anything.

Comment: Try `#!/usr/bin/env python3` with no space.

Comment: I have tried many variations of the shebang. I have a different script that had #!/usr/bin/python3.7 and that one worked by clicking on it, and then execute.
This time, I have two different scripts, both with the same shebang, and nothing happens. All the files are set to the right permissions. 
I am not sure what else I can try.

Comment: Are you sure the executable bit is set - `chmod +x filename.py`? My Pi seems to have disappeared, so I can't replicate your situation. There's really not much else I can think of...

Comment: Yes the executable was set properly. I was able to make it work by creating a .desktop file. I found instructions to another answer on this site: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49157570/run-python-script-through-shell-script-by-double-click)